# How to design a sharp 200kHz band pass filter

Tags: active-filter, plc, power-line-communication

I have made an a fm communication system to send audio through power lines. The center frequency is 100khz or 200 khz and maximum frequency deviation is ±10khz(with no IF stage).

The modulator and demodulator work fine when connected directly with wires. Now I want to use 220v power lines as transmission medium.
If the receiver board is connected to the input and powerlines using a small ferrite toroid as an isolated transformer.
 The powerline-side is 2 turns series with a 100nf capacitor and the receiver-side is 12 turns paralleled with a capacitor(the resonant frequency of 12turn side paralleled with capacitor was 200khz) I tested the filter in lab with a spectrum analyzer, unfortunately the Q factor was too low. The spectrum analyzer was 50ohm input/output put a 1k resistor in series with the input port of the analyzer to enhance Q with little effect.
The transmitter device was already off, I connected the output of the above BPF to an audio amplifier directly (without fm demodulator) and I was surprised with an irritating noise in the frequency of 4-6khz range.
After some time I discovered that the source of the noise is a nearby CFL lamp powered by the same powerline! I designed a 3 stage RC HPF with cutoff frequency of 50khz but it couldn't eliminate the 4khz noise completely and the noise power was still high.
There are multiple choices with this design:
1-I can use an active filter. I designed it using nu-hertz filter solution program.but it needed some 4.7pF or 6.8pF capacitors to which I think opamp's parasitic capacitances are comparable and I worried it may cause error in center frequency and filter response.
2- I can use 455 khz ceramic filters(and change system frequency to 455khz). but unfortunately they are hard to buy for me.another problem is that most of these filters have low BW (less than 20khz).

3- I can use a crystal filter as used in SSB communication circuits , but they are hard to design for low frequency.

Can you please help me which one to proceed?

Comment: It's probably not much help for you, but back in the old days with FSK modems the filtering problems were similarly tough. I used a 6-pole transmit and a 10-pole receive filter, memory serving.

Comment: thanks. filters in fsk modems were passive or active?can you please show me some examples? @jonk

Comment: They were active. I'd have to dig up very old records -- that was in... 1980... I think?

Comment: I'm an analog guy myself, but depending on the signal-to-noise you need, have you considered looking at a ADC+DSP solution?

Comment: @HamidReza For a 200kHz center frequency, 20kHz passband with 0.01dB ripple, 40kHz stopband and 80dB attenuation, a Cauer (elliptic) filter would need a 7th order (while inverse Chebyshev a 10th order, with 0.01dB@fc, to mimick the Cauer). At 200kHz you're still fine with opamps, though you might run into minor bandwidth limitations, unless you get more expensive opamps, but it might be preferable compared to tuning inductors which will have to be relatively large for this frequency.

Comment: Why do you think you are required to use caps in the lower pF range? You can tell nu-Hertz that larger capacitors are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

With TI’s free active filter design for any filter type Bessel , Linear Phase , maximally flat Chebychev etc up to 10th order where 8th order is just a quad OpAmp and 8RC’s with choice for nearest tolerance options but you MUST DEFINE;

- BPF -3dB passband width , centre f , band stop width and attenuation at stop then type

If you define the noise level and BW then signal level and BW and probably want Bessel for flat group delay then you will know SNR from which you can determine BER from related curves.

Comment: THANKS FOR REPLY, so is it OK to use capacitor in the "pF" range in active filters? Aren't parasitic capacitors in a real op-amp capable of causing problems in this case?

Comment: @HamidReza. Why so hung up about pF capacitors? Adjust R so that the value of C is at least 10 to 100 times the parasitic capacitance. Use JFET op-amps for better performance.

Comment: Many PCB design tools can tell you trace capacitance over ground plane or lower without per mm or cm so you can prototype with an estimate within a couple pF then reduce stray tolerance errors. In RF you can learn how to control 0.1 pF

Comment: @HamidReza It is expected with TI’s Filter Designer that you know about basic optimization of Op Amp passive parts for load current limits, input bias current offset voltage matching AND **changing impedance vs f in general such that RC products stay the same**

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple RLC band pass filter like this: -

[image]

With R at 1000 ohms, C at 7.72 nF (you can parallel capacitors to get this) and L at 82 uH you get this: -

[image]

[Interactive filter page](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html).

Rejection at 10 kHz is 45 dB. 3 dB bandwidth is about 20 kHz (can be made tighter of course). You could also buy an inductor with a tuning slug for accurately setting this up.

If the CFL lamp was turned off, did the system work correctly over AC wiring?

Also be aware of just the amount of signal you might receive from the basic 220 volts (assuming 50 Hz). If you look at a low Q band pass filter (possibly like what you have at present) you might see something like this: -

[image]

Now, if you analysed the slopes of the graph and calculated the rejection you would get at 50 Hz, it will be in the realm of 72 dB. In other words the 220 V AC on the output of your signal transformer will still have an amplitude of about 55 mV RMS and could be significant enough to make life hard for your demodulation circuit.